# NDK support for ARMv6

Tags: android

Hi,

I tried to run an openCV facial detection app on my Samsung s5360 which has a 2.3.6 android version. I keep getting INSTALL_FAILED_CPU_ABI_INCOMPATIBLE error message. After some digging up I came into the conclusion that the reason was the latest NDK revision 8d doesn't support ARMv6. Is there a suitable NDK version that would support my phone?

**Thanks in advance**

Comment: What is your setting for APP_ABI? For ARMv5TE & ARMv6 it should be armeabi. You'll find this info in docs/CPU-ARCH-ABIS.html.

Comment: Awesome! you just solved my problem. The APP_ABI was set to armeabi-v7a, changed it to armeabi and it works! Thanks a lot. If you can post it as an answer I can close the thread as answered. :)